# Cache _source in memory in elastisearch

Tags: caching, search, elasticsearch

I am using _source field in my sort script to sort docs based on complex logic involving multi level nested fields. But `accessing _source from disk for each matched document is performing poorly, giving me ~ 3 sec response times.`

Is there any way to improve this by caching the _source field in memory? I am willing to pay for more memory, in order to improve the latency. If not, is it possible to extend elasticsearch to build/use this cache yourself?

Edit:
Here's my use case: I have hotel docs which have multiple rooms and each room has day wise price and inventory.

```
hotel > rooms > dailyPriceInventories
```

I have filters on all three levels. Say hotels with 5 star rating, rooms with "free wifi" amenity and having inventory of 2 for dates d1-d2 and between price p1-p2.

Now for sorting, I want to calculate minimum price from all matched nested docs. But this isn't possible with regular sort, as I cannot specify filters on multiple nested levels inside it. So I have to utilize script sorting. But inside a script accessing nested level fields is only possible with the _source field.

Mapping:

```
"hotel": {
        "properties": {
           "name": {
              "type": "string",
           },
           "id": {
              "type": "string",
           },
           "roomTypes": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                 "roomCode": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                 },
                 "roomType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                 },
                 "amenities": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed",
                 },
                 "invPrice": {
                      "type": "nested",
                      "properties": {
                         "date": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                         },
                         "inventory": {
                            "type": "integer",
                         },
                         "price": {
                            "type": "double",
                         }
                      }
                   }
              }
           },
           "starRating": {
              "type": "short",
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document as well as your complex sort logic?

Comment: I have filters on nesting level 2 & 3, and I have to find highest rated 3rd level doc. This cannot be accomplished with regular sort as it allows filter at only single level.

Comment: Still, my previous comment holds. Help us help you ;-)

Comment: @Val Added the mapping and use case. Complex sort logic is all the nested filters I have to apply.

Comment: can you get rid of the nested in your mapping or is this essential? I would just use type:object. Your problem is that nested documents are separate lucene documents and that's why you can't sort on them directly. With objects, you can simply use hotel.rooms. dailyPriceInventories. If you can't get rid of nested, you might be able to copy the nested field to a field in the parent document and sort on that. I don't ever use nested but I recall there might be a way to do this.

Comment: We can actually sort on a nested field, that is not a problem. Problem is limitation of nested filter inside sort to a single level. Also using object instead of nested flattens values and looses association.